# Not able to re-render the page after updating redux state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

Here i am getting the list of google drive files in '/dashboard/gdrive'. There is one more event of uploading a new file. On uploading the redux state shows that the new file is stored in state but whil re-rendering i am not able to access the store states.

Here is the codeblock

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {logoutUser} from "./../../actions/authActions.js";
import {syncCloud} from "./../../actions/cloudActions.js";
import {uploadFile} from "./../../actions/cloudActions.js";

class Gdrive extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            file: null
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleCancelEvent = this.handleCancelEvent.bind(this);
    }
    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            file: e.target.files[0]
        });
    }
    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('filename', this.state.file);
        this.props.uploadFile(data);
    }
    handleCancelEvent(){
        this.setState({
            file: null
        })
    }
    render() {    
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>fileid</th><th>filename</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.cloud.files.data.map(file =>(
                        <tr>
                            <td>{file.id}</td>
                            <td>{file.name}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <fieldset>
                <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label>filename</label>
                    <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} name= "filename"></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Upload</button> 
                    <button onClick={this.handleCancelEvent}>Cancel</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
Gdrive.propTypes = {
    logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    cloud: state.cloud
});
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { logoutUser, syncCloud, uploadFile }
  )(Gdrive);
```

and here is uploadFile action

```
export const uploadFile = (file) => dispatch => {
axios.post('/gdrive/upload', file)
.then(rslt => {
    dispatch({
        type: UPLOAD_FILE,
        payload: {id: rslt.data.fileid, name: rslt.data.filename}
    })
})
.catch(err => {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err
    })
});
```

}

Here is the reducer

```
import {SYNC_CLOUD, UPLOAD_FILE} from './../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    files: {}
};

export default function(state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case SYNC_CLOUD:
            return{
                ...state,
                files: action.payload
            };
        case UPLOAD_FILE: 
            return{
                ...state,
                files: state.files.data.concat(action.payload),
            };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vahih.png)

Comment: Can you post your reducer too? Do you get this error after your file upload api  call is successfull?

Comment: Are you appending to array in reducer ?  error is because `this.props.cloud.files` is not their is not array after upload

Comment: @santosh I have posted the reducer. I got where the error is Initially the files are stored in file->data->{} but after uploading a new file the state changes to file->{} Now i want to just change the file->data not the file. Can you tell how to change the part of state

Comment: I couldnt write everything in comment thats why I have posted in answer. I didnt understand why files is object . If you explain from where file has data property I will modify the answer accordingly. Also, I am not sure about SYNC_CLOUD action. Looks like both action does the same thing, concatenating the existing files array. Can you please explain? If  it is then there should be only one action saying, UPDATE_FILES which simply does [...state, action.payload]. I will modify the answer if you will explain

Comment: @santosh files was coming from the result of google drive api. SYNC_CLOUD was connecting user to google drive and listing the files on dashboard by creating the redux state whereas UPLOAD_FILES allow user to upload a new file on drive and update the state.

Comment: @santosh Got it, I changed file to file->data in redux state. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your reducer is wrongly mapped.The key here is to declare inital state as empty files rather empty object. And also concatinating the existing array with the response from api(payload).

Change ur reducer to something like this:

```
 import {SYNC_CLOUD, UPLOAD_FILE} from './../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    files: []
};

export default function(state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case SYNC_CLOUD:
            return{
                ...state,
                files: action.payload
            };
        case UPLOAD_FILE: 
            return{
                [...state, action.payload],
            };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

And change the render function to

```
<tbody>
       {this.props.cloud.files.map(file =>(
            <tr>
                 <td>{file.id}</td>
                  <td>{file.name}</td>
              </tr>
                ))}
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapDispatchToProps` parameter to `connect` needs to be a function. Either do something like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch => bindActionCreators(
    { logoutUser, syncCloud, uploadFile },
    dispatch
)
```

Or, in pass `null` as your `mapDispatchToProps` and in your component use the action creator like this `this.props.dispatch(uploadFile(data))`